# How to run ionic cordova live-reload on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, livereload

#### How to run ionic cordova live-reload on ios ?

Following to the [ionicframework'](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/livereload) doc `ionic cordova run ios -l --external` command will "start a live-reload server on all addresses and deploy the app to an iOS device using Cordova"

Well for me it logs out

```
> ng run app:ionic-cordova-serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100 --platform=ios
[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: context.getProjectMetadata is not a function
[ng] See "/private/var/folders/g3/z8_4pwdj0ps1jdm9bnt8dcrc0000gn/T/ng-GhO4vZ/angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).
```

I tried to replace the plateform `ios` by the `browser` one but I got the same error.

angular-errors.log :
[image: angular-error]

Note that running `ionic cordova run ios --external` without `-l` works well, `http://172.20.10.3:8000/` shows my webapp.

Anyone has manage to make the live-reload works on IOS ? And how ?

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 5 apps I use the following to run in a WKWebView (of my custom debug app binary) or Mobile Safari browser on iOS:

`ionic serve --no-open --consolelogs --external`

`--no-open` suppresses the launching of a browser tab

`--consolelogs` console logs to the command line

`--external` makes it available on your local network

I then load the development machine IP address and port in my WKWebView (via UI form fields) or browser location bar and I get live reload debugging as I code. e.g. `http://192.168.1.3:8100`

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve